# Call function in auto complete textbox field has not empty and focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant to call the function when that textbax value has changed, that textbox is auto complete field. Also cal the same function while page load if the textbox has set by value.

```
$("#fso_ot").bind('focusout', function() {
    alert("here fun goes");
});
```

i want to call the same function while that textbox has assigned by value.
Some time i set that text box value while load.

```
<input type="text" id="fso_ot" value="OP" />
```

if that text has value mean i want to call the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change()` function,
At below code this would  trigger if the value is not empty during page load and bind this to element `#fso_ot` for `onchange` event

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    if($('#fso_ot').val() != ''){
        //this trigger if value is not empty during page load
        $('#fso_ot').trigger("change"); 
    }

   // this would trigger when value is changed on input
    $("#fso_ot").change( function() {
        alert("here fun goes");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Here change function wont work for this autocomplete textbox. what i do? help me